# Water normals don't offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, cg

I am working on my water shader but I have run into some problems. It looks like my normals aren't getting the same offset as my vertexes. You can see a white plane belof my water where the shadow of the water is cast upon, exept another white plane which is not a object but most likely the normals of my water mesh that didn't move block a part of the shadow. PLEASE I really need some help with this can't find anyone who knows what this is.

[image]

This is my code:

```
Shader "Custom/NoobShader_04" {
     Properties {
         _Color ("Color", Color) = (0,0.55,0.83,1)
         _Diffuse ("Diffuse Map", 2D) = "white" {}
         _Displacement ("Displacement Map", 2D) = "white" {}

         _Scale ("Wave Scale", float) = 0.7
         _Frequency ("Frequency", float) = 0.6
         _Speed ("Speed", float) = 0.5

     }
     SubShader {
         Pass{
         Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase"}
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag

         float4 _Color;
         sampler2D _Displacement;
         sampler2D _Diffuse;

         float _Scale;
         float _Frequency;
         float _Speed;

         float4 _LightColor0;

         struct VertexOutput
         {
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
             float3 nor : NORMAL;
             float4 col : COLOR;
             float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         struct VertexInput
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
             float3 normal : NORMAL;
             float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         struct FragmentOutput
         {
             float4 color : COLOR;
         };

         VertexOutput vert (VertexInput i)
         {
             VertexOutput VOUT;

             float4 disp = tex2Dlod(_Displacement, float4(i.texcoord.x * _Frequency + (_Time.x * _Speed), i.texcoord.y * _Frequency + (_Time.x * _Speed),0.0,0.0));
             float4 newPos = i.vertex;
             float3 newNor = i.normal;
             newPos.y += _Scale * disp.y; 
             newNor.y += _Scale * disp.y;

             VOUT.nor = newNor;
             VOUT.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,newPos);
             VOUT.tex = i.texcoord;

             float3 normalDirection = normalize( mul(float4(newNor,0.0),_World2Object).xyz);
             float3 lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
             float atten = 1.0;

             float3 diffuseRefflection = atten * _LightColor0.xyz * _Color.rgb *  max( 0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));

             VOUT.col = float4(diffuseRefflection, 1.0);

             return VOUT;
         }

         FragmentOutput frag(VertexOutput v) 
         {
             FragmentOutput FOUT;
             float4 tex = tex2D(_Diffuse,float4(v.tex.x * _Frequency + (_Time.x * _Speed), v.tex.y * _Frequency + (_Time.x * _Speed),0.0,0.0));
             FOUT.color = tex * v.col + UNITY_LIGHTMODEL_AMBIENT.xyzw;
             return FOUT;
         }
         ENDCG
         }
     } 
     FallBack "Diffuse"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see a white plane belof my water where the shadow of the water
>   is cast upon, exept another white plane which is not a object but most
>   likely the normals of my water mesh that didn't move block a part of
>   the shadow.

I tried your shader and I can't see any plane, except the one I add to a scene to receive the casted shadow. In any case, water's normals don't have anything to do with the plane.

> It looks like my normals aren't getting the same offset as my
>   vertexes

Again, not sure what you mean here. Offset has no effect on normals, because they express an orientation, not a position.

If you mean that the projected shadow on the plane, doesn't account for the vertex offset, it's because the auto generated **shadow caster pass**, can't take in consideration the vertex offset. So you probably need to explicitly implement it.

Something like:

```
Pass
    { 
        Name "ShadowCaster"
        Tags { "LightMode" = "ShadowCaster" }

        Fog {Mode Off}
        ZWrite On ZTest Less Cull Off
        Offset 1, 1

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"


        v2f vert( appdata_full v )
        {
            v2f o;
            //TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER(o) this is how default shadow are casted
            o.pos = ...;// put here your calculation taking into account the vertex offset. Basically repeating the same calculation you wrote for forward pass in regards to vertex position

          return o;
        }

        float4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
        {
            fixed4 texcol = tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv );
            clip( texcol.a - _Cutoff );
            SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
        }
        ENDCG
    }
```